# How to secure/protect usage of Algolia's front end api key?

Tags: algolia, api-key

From the official tutorials on https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/, Algolia requires you to code the key into your application and used with each api request. If someone were to dig this up, what's to prevent them from spamming search requests with your api key?

Answer (score 0):

> If someone were to dig this up, what's to prevent them from spamming search requests with your api key?

Do you want the cruel truth? Nothing...

Unfortunately in a web app does not exist anyway of securing secrets, be they api-keys, tokens or any other name convention that may be used.

In a web app all is needed is to use F12 or view the page source and search for them in the raw html and JavaScript.

You can try to use [JavaScript obfuscation](https://obfuscator.io/) to make it hard to find but will still be easy to reverse engineer. Even in a mobile app that have their code obfuscated and released as a binary is easy to extract this secrets.

If you want to understand a little more about Mobile Api Security Techinques please read [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles to find how api-keys, access tokens, HMAC and other techniques can be used and bypassed. While the article was wrote in the context of a mobile API is still valid in a web app context for the security techniques used to protect the API.

## Possible Solution

The best approach is to always delegate your web app access to third part API's to a backend you can control.

In this backend you can then use a User Behaviour Analytics(UBA) solution to monitor bad use of this third part access.

Once UBA can be complex and expensive to deploy you could start by using the new [Google reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) across all pages of your web app. ReCaptcha V3 does not require direct user interaction once it works on the background to differentiate humans from bots.

So I would have the web app requesting the Agolia search to my backend that would use reCaptcha V3 protection to differentiate abuse in the search functionality by bots or attackers.

Remember that this approach has the huge benefit of **never reveal** your Agolia API Key, thus attackers can never directly use it.